# Chamar função Javascript com onclick com conteúdo carregado de div

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tenho uma `div` que tem seu conteúdo carregado após o carregamento do resto da página. Ela é chamada por um botão via AJAX. Eu tenho outro botão dentro desse conteúdo que chamaria uma função Javascript para confirmar um direcionamento de paginas. Mas quando ele está dentro do conteúdo carregado o botão não funciona.

Segue o código da função.

```
<script language="Javascript">

function confirmacao(aluno) {
     var resposta = confirm("Deseja remover esse aluno?");

     if (resposta == true) {
          window.location.href = "del_aluno_done.php?aluno="+aluno;
     }
}
</script>
```

Segue código do botão

```
<a href='javascript:func()'onclick='confirmacao('$aluno;)'>
```

Comment: Eu começaria arrumando o link (botão). Já que ele tará que confirmar, chame a função func() de dentro da função confirmacao, caso necessário.

Comment: Conseguiu pôr isto a funcionar?

Comment: Olá... Cara, conseguiu fazer funcionar? Eu entendi seu problema, e to passando pelo mesmo. Preciso fazer uma chamada de um botão, após ser carregado via ajax.

Answer (score 2):

O seu código tem alguns erros. Não sei se foi por pressa a colocar/simplificar o exemplo, ou se tem erros no seu código mesmo.

Uma vez que você juntou a tag jQuery aqui fica uma sugestao retirando todo o javascript do seu HTML.

1 - Dê uma classe ao botão
2 - Se lhe chama botão, pode ser boa ideia usar um `<button>` em vez de um `<a>` principalmente por não haver nenhum link para clickar, só um comportamento do javascript que deve ser corrido...
3 - A informação, possivelmente passada via PHP, que é referente a esse elemento pode ser guardada num campo `data-`

Então, em vêz de

```
<a href='javascript:func()'onclick='confirmacao('$aluno;)'>
```

Pode usar

```
<button type="button" data-aluno="<?php echo $aluno; ?>" class="botaoAluno">Clique aqui</button>
```

E no Javascript/jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.botaoAluno', function(){
        func();
        var aluno = $(this).data('aluno');
        var resposta = confirm("Deseja remover esse aluno?");

         if (resposta == true) {
              window.location.href = "del_aluno_done.php?aluno=" + aluno;
         }
         // ou pode manter a funcao à parte e chamar `confirmacao(aluno);` aqui dentro
    });
});
```

Comment: Não funcionou, quando eu clico no botão, nada acontece. Quando eu tento chamar a função de dentro da div que foi carregada depois do resto da pagina, não funciona.

Comment: @user3127841, junte o seu HTML à pergunta para eu poder ajustar a resposta. Sem HTML é dificil acertar mais certeiro do que eu fiz.

Comment: Eu não tenho como responder minha própria pergunta =/ mas eu copiei o que você mandou aqui, será que é por que está sendo carregado o conteudo da div que tem o botão, depois do resto da pagina?